# Serilog not reading from logging section in appsettings.json

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

This my logger config:

```
var loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
        //.MinimumLevel
        //.Information() //These are not working from appsettings.json possibly because we are using Serilog?
        //.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration,"Logging")
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .WriteTo.File(
            $"{configuration.GetValue<string>("logFilePath")}{DateTime.Now.Date:yyyy_MM_dd}_{assemblyName}.log");
        
var logger = loggerConfig.CreateLogger();

services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
    {
        loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();
        loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(logger);
    });
```

This is the logging section of my `appsettings.json`:

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Microsoft": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Warning"
    }
```

The logging is not following the settings from levels from setting and seems like defaulting to information.

I also tried the following and it did not work

```
"Logging": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Override": {
        "System": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Warning"
      }
    }
```

Comment: its not serilog config

Comment: It's the generic logging config, is it not possible for Serilog to use it? I want to not change it if I decide to use any other logging framework

Comment: no its not generic config, its config for default logger microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sample of configuration Serilog: uncomment line to have a json ouput

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "C:/Users/itki4060/Desktop/DBLite/log/log.txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Month",
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 13
          //"formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

the you could use the config like this:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
                                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");


var config = builder.Build();

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
                                      .CreateLogger();
```

---

Log is static:

```
Log.Information("i am logging");
```

Comment: Is there no way to use the Logging section with Serilog. If I decided to switch my Ilogger implementation to something else, I would not want to change the logging setting

Comment: Each logger has its settings ....